# Best practice add multiple object at one page on storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, xcode7, xcode-storyboard

I am wondering what is the best practice for creating a page in storyboard that consist of multiple object (It can be imageView, View, label, etc). Look at this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRkP0GWWGK-WTJoYzE1ZEltQnM/view?usp=sharing), I feel ridiculous adding new object under the bottom view that is outside the page view.

I know a little how to arrange view with relativeLayout etc in Android. But how can I arrange this page with storyboard and autolayout? I want to arrange a page that consist of multiple object with different size. This maybe a stupid question, but I mean it a lot for me as a newbie developer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without knowing more about what you are trying to do.

It looks to me like it might be a good candidate for using a UITableView. You'd create a table view and add cells for each of the items that you want.

You could also create a scroll view and install the items on the scroll view, either through custom code, or with AutoLayout if there are a fixed number of items.

You could also use a UICollectionView if you need a layout other than a vertical scrolling list of items.

Edit your question with more details on what you're trying to do if you want more specific help.

Comment: Edited: I want to arrange a page that consist of multiple object with different size. I know there are few option using UICollectionView and UITableView (but this will getting ridiculous with static cell in UIViewController). I think scrollview is the best suit with this problem, but I can't see the object I dropped after all my page is already full with all of my object. Thank you @Duncan C.